# Spring test classes not reading application.yml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this class:

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({QueryClientProps.class})
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public QueryClientProps queryClientProps() {
       return new QueryClientProps();
    }
//more code
}
```

and this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "orderapi")
@Setter
@Getter
public class QueryClientProps {
    private CouchbaseContext couchbase = new CouchbaseContext();
}
```

The problem is, when I try to use to `queryClientProps` object, all the fields of `CouchbaseContext` are `null`. This mean, it is not reading the `application.yml` files. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: The exact same thing when done in `src/main/java` loads application.yml. But it does not work for `src/test/java`.

Answer (score 0):

So, found the answer. Adding `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)` to my `StepDefs` class worked.